# Jquery date comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi iam using the following code for comparing the entered date with current date... But it is not working...

```
$('#<%=txtOrderDate.ClientID%>').change(function() {
            var date = $('#<%=txtOrderDate.ClientID%>').val();
            var arrDate = date.split("/");
            var today = new Date();
            var useDate = new Date(arrDate[2], arrDate[1] - 1, arrDate[0]);
            if (useDate > today) {
                alert('Please Enter the correctDate');
                $('#<%=txtOrderDate.ClientID%>').val('');
            }
        });
```

Help me if anybody knows it... Advance thanks....

Comment: Exactly how is it not working? Is there an error message? How is the result different from what you expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i tried to copy your code and this works on my machine

```
            $('#txtbox').change(function() {
                var date = $(this).val();
                var arrDate = date.split("/");
                var today = new Date();
                useDate = new Date(arrDate[2], arrDate[1] -1, arrDate[0]);

                if (useDate > today) {
                    alert('Please Enter the correctDate');
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            });
```

i removed the var from the useDate, and take note that new Dateparameter is (y,m,d).