# Textboxfor mvc3 date formatting and date validation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've decided to get started with MVC 3 and I ran into this issue while trying to redo one of my web apps to MVC3.

I've got projects setup this way:

```
public class Project
{
    public int      ProjectID       { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="A name is required")]
    public string   Name            { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Team")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="A team is required")]
    public int      TeamId          { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Start Date")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="A Start Date is required")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, DataFormatString="{0:d}")]
    public DateTime StartDate       { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("End Date")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="An End Date is required")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime EndDate         { get; set; }
}
```

And my entry form is written this way for the dates:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "datepicker", id="txtStartDate" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "datepicker", id = "txtEndDate" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is that the textbox are now displaying 01/Jan/0001 00:00:00.
So first: how can I get the date to be formated to shortdatestring?
I've found an [MVC2 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088139/how-to-format-the-value-in-a-strongy-typed-view-when-using-asp-net-mvcs-html-tex) which advised to create an EditorTemplates folder in the SharedFolder and use EditorFor instead but that did not seem to be working with MVC3 . It also seemed to prevent adding classes easily like it is with TextBoxFor

And secondly once that is fixed I've got a special validation system that I need to put in place. I need to have the End Date to be AFTER the Start Date. I'm thinking of doing the check with a javascript i found http://www.datejs.com but is there a way to do the validation directly on my class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your edit template try this

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "datePicker" })
```

Source: [MVC 3 Editor Template with DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249955/mvc-3-editor-template-with-datetime)

jQuery DateTime comparisons

```
$('#txtbox').change(function() {
            var date = $(this).val();
            var arrDate = date.split("/");
            var today = new Date();
            useDate = new Date(arrDate[2], arrDate[1] -1, arrDate[0]);

            if (useDate > today) {
                alert('Please Enter the correctDate');
                $(this).val('');
            }
        });
```

Source: [Jquery date comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344351/jquery-date-comparison)

Comment: Thanks for links! My dates still show 01/01/001 though. But I guess I can get that re-written in jquery.

Comment: Might be a stupid question but are the dates populated prior to be sent out to the view?

Comment: I don't see how they could be. My HomeController is pretty straightforward:
`public PartialViewResult EntryForm()
        {
            ViewBag.Teams = projectDB.Teams.OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();

            var project = new Project();

            return PartialView(project);
        }`

Comment: Try setting the Date as a nullable type, otherwise it will automatically get instantiated to the system default 1/1/0001. http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-minvalue

Answer (score 6):

there is a considerably easier way of doing this. Just use a `TextBox` rather than a `TextBoxFor`

```
@Html.TextBox("ReturnDepartureDate", 
    Model.ReturnDepartureDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

this has the advantage of adding all the unobtrusive JavaScript elements, etc. Also less code!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this example

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.dateofbirth, new { Value = @Model.dateofbirth.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") })
```

Comment: It's a little workaround! It creates an second value-attribute. It works only if a capital-V is used.

Answer (score 2):

If you decorate your viewmodel object with the following you'll only see the date portion within the text box.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Then on your page you can simply do the following

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
```

Note that this is using standard MVC3. I don't have a custom Date editor template.

All credit for this answer goes to [assign date format with data annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252979/assign-format-of-datetime-with-data-annotations)

Answer (score 1):

Too late but might be it can help to someone:

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
public DateTime? DOB{ get; set; }
```

HTML:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DOB, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", 
          new { @placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY", @au19tocomplete="off" })
```

JavaScript to add the calendar to the control:

```
$('#DOB').datepicker({changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, 
         minDate: '01/01/1900',  maxDate: new Date});
```

Answer (score 0):

// datimetime displays in the datePicker is 11/24/2011 12:00:00 AM

// you could split this by space and set the value to date only

Script:

```
    if ($("#StartDate").val() != '') {
        var arrDate = $('#StartDate').val().split(" ");
        $('#StartDate').val(arrDate[0]);
    }
```

Markup:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, "Start Date")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "date-picker-needed" })
    </div>
```

Hopes this helps..