# Display only date and no time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

In MVC razor, I am putting current date in the database like this..

```
model.Returndate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
```

Since the database field is a datetime datatype and I am converting the current date to string format, this is not working.. how can I do this? I am doing the string format because I want the date in mm/dd/yyyy format and not in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss time format..

EDIT:

In the controller I have

```
var model = new ViewModel();
model.ReturnDate = DateTime.Now;            
return PartialView("PartialView", model);
```

In the partialview, I have

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Returndate)
```

This is where its displaying the date as Date and Time together... I want just the date to be displayed. Not the time. I hope this edit explains better.

Comment: don't worry about the 00:00:00 (midnight). Just format the output `ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");` to be able to see exactly what you want.

Comment: Save the data in the database as `DateTime`. You do the string formatting on the OUTPUT... Only format it to the end viewer.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

If the column type is DateTime in SQL then it will store a time where you pass one or not.

It'd be better to save the date properly:

```
model.ReturnDate = DateTime.Now;
```

and then format it when you need to display it:

```
@Html.Label(Model.ReturnDate.ToShortDateString())
```

Or if you're using EditorFor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReturnDate.ToShortDateString())
```

or

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReturnDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

To add a property to your model add this code:

```
public string ReturnDateForDisplay
{
    get
    {
       return this.ReturnDate.ToString("d");
    }
}
```

Then in your PartialView:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReturnDateForDisplay)
```

EDIT:

I just want to clarify for this answer that by my saying 'If you're using EditorFor', that means you need to have an EditorFor template for the type of value you're trying to represent.

Editor templates are a cool way of managing repetitive controls in MVC:

http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/

You can use them for naive types like String as I've done above; but they're especially great for letting you template a set of input fields for a more complicated data type.

Comment: not sure who downvoted this.. but I am not using the HTML.label to display this.. I am using HTML.EditorFor(model => model.Returndate) how do I format the display in this case...

Comment: That was just an example of how to format your result; I'll update my answer.

Comment: I think if the value is *logically* only a date, it's worth storing just the date part as well, even if the time is going to be stripped on display anyway.

Comment: The `Label` parameter isn't the date time.

Comment: Indeed, but ZVenue didn't actually say how he was displaying it at the point I wrote that snippet, I was simply trying to illustrate how you should save the data intact, and then format it to the way you require when you display it.

Comment: @Russ: the editorfor update you made did not work. Its giving me an error "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Comment: Please see my Edit to the original post. This should explain better.

Comment: John skeets answer has everything you need, if you do get that template error again, consider making in a get property on your model that returns the formatted date.

Comment: @RussC: Yes I am getting that template error.. and I am not sure what you mean by "get property on your model that returns the formatted date".. Appreciate your help.

Comment: you should remove '@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReturnDate.ToShortDateString())' from the answer because that does not work.

Comment: Actually it works fine but you have to have implemented an Editor template for the type of value. Here's a handy guide: http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/

Comment: Editor templates are cool but unnecessarily complicated here when you can just use a DataType annotation.

Comment: @mkataja Yes; but check the dates; this was MVC3; Also, and more relevant; You can use a data *type* annotation, but data format is a different beast; we always knew it was a day time, he just wanted to render it differently.

Comment: I was getting the error "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions." as described above.  Converting it to a string and then displaying it in the view worked for me...                   @{String DateEdited = (string)Convert.ChangeType(item.DateLastEdited.ToShortDateString(), typeof(string));}
                    @DateEdited

Comment: Will this have an Impact on SQL If we are using EF Code first Approach ?

Answer (score 147):

Just had to deal with this scenario myself  - found a really easy way to do this, simply annotate your property in the model like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? SomeDateProperty { get; set; }
```

It will hide the time button from the date picker too.

Sorry if this answer is a little late ;)

Comment: Just what I needed. Excellent!

Comment: I had a sitation recently where chrome put funny stuff in when input type is date, part of html5 i think, I wanted to use jquery datepicker instead so I went with DataType.Text - that still allowed me to use formatting cool enough

Comment: No need to apologise for being late, posting answers to old questions can be a great help for people who aren't OP. This is the answer I was looking for as I knew it was possible but couldn't remember how, and you posted it 3 years ago. If anything you are incredibly early.

Comment: if the date comes from a database i don't know how this could help... can't figure it out

Comment: This isn't working, it says there is no method called ToString or even ToShortDateString() when trying to use it with DisplayFor(modelItem = item.migrationdate.ToShortDateString())

Comment: FYI, it doesn't work with me without date format
`[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212527/how-to-set-default-value-to-the-inputtype-date

Answer (score 43):

This works if you want to display in a TextBox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Employee.DOB, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")
```

Comment: date will be shown incorrectly if browser has different format in settings than "dd-MM-yyyy", i.e "MM-dd-yyyy"

Answer (score 17):

The date/time in the datebase won't be a *formatted* version at all. It'll just be the date/time itself. How you *display* that date/time when you extract the value from the database is a different matter. I strongly suspect you really just want:

```
model.Returndate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

or possibly

```
model.Returndate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
```

Yes, if you look at the database using SQL Server Studio or whatever, you'll now see midnight - but that's irrelevant, and when you fetch the date out of the database and display it to a user, *then* you can apply the relevant format.

EDIT: In regard to your edited question, the problem isn't with the model - it's how you specify the view. You should use something like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Returndate.Date.ToString("d"))
```

where `d` is the [standard date and time format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for the short date pattern (which means it'll take the current cultural settings into account).

That's the bit I've been saying repeatedly - that when you *display the date/time to the user*, that's the time to format it as a date without a time.

EDIT: If this doesn't work, there should be a way of decorating the model or view with a format string - or something like that. I'm not really an MVC person, but it feels like there *ought* to be a good way of doing this declaratively...

Comment: The DateTime.Now.Date still displays the time along with the date.

Comment: @ZVenue: Displays it where? You should be *storing* a DateTime value, and using a date-only format specifier wherever you're *displaying* the date. The code you've given (setting a property in the model) is presumably for storage, so it doesn't matter that it's got a time of midnight.

Comment: Jon's suggesting what I was talking about, saving the date to SQL as it stands; you can then just format your date appropriately when you print it.

Comment: Sorry I didnt say what I was doing with that date time .. I am displaying it in a partial view like  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Returndate)..thasts where this is displayed as date and time together... I want just the date to be displayed in this html.editorfor

Comment: Please see my Edit to the original post. This should explain better.

Comment: @ZVenue: Edited the answer... basically it was exactly what I've been saying before: you need to change how you *display* the value, not how you *store* it.

Comment: @Russ: It happens sometimes :(

Comment: @Jon:I am getting this error when I used your edit code for html.editorfor...."Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions"....at run time

Comment: @ZVenue: Then you need to look on ASP.NET MVC tutorials for how to apply formatting to values - which isn't really specific to DateTime. I'll have a look too...

Comment: @ZVenue: It could well be that DisplayFormatAttribute is what you're after: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx

Comment: @ZVenue: Have a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033902/textboxfor-mvc3-date-formatting-and-date-validation

Comment: "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions" above html.editorfor won't work

Comment: @John: Hmm - not sure then, to be honest. But hopefully the answer at least gives the flavour of what's wrong, even if the MVC-specific bits aren't quite right.

Answer (score 10):

You can modify your ViewModel as below:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Comment: This solution also solves the problem of Chrome's datepicker conflict. If you just specify Datatype.Date in Viewmodel, Chrome uses its own version of datepicker in textbox. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can apply custom date time format using  `ToString` like:

```
DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Further reading on `DateTime.ToString` formats pattern can be found [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx).

**Edit:** After your question edit, Just like what other suggested you should apply the date format at your view:

```
model.Returndate = DateTime.Now.Date;

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Returndate.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

Comment: that won't help the issue of saving the date though.

Comment: Can't he save it with calling `model.Returndate.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")`?

Comment: Thats a problem.. I am putting that value in a datetime field in the db. So this will not work..please see my original post.

Comment: Shouldn't it be .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")? mm is minutes, not months!

Comment: @Bodrich: thanks, updated, I just copy paste his pattern though.

Comment: @ZVenue: you can load it the same way `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact` and apply the pattern, but I think @Jon answer is better apply here.

Comment: Please see my Edit to the original post. This should explain better.

Comment: @ZVenue you should put the string format there then, check my answer edit.

Comment: @Jalal: Again I am getting the same error..."Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Comment: How does specifying the format deal with localization?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a for loop such as the one below.

Change @item.StartDate to **@item.StartDate.Value.ToShortDateString()**

This will remove the time just in case you can't annotate your property in the model like in my case.

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>Type</th>
   <th>Start Date</th>
  </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.TestList) {
      <tr>
        <td>@item.TypeName</td>
        <td>@item.StartDate.Value.ToShortDateString()</td>
      </tr>
      }
</table>
```

Comment: <td>@item.StartDate.ToShortDateString()</td>

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure in Razor but in ASPX you do:

```
 <%if (item.Modify_Date != null)
  {%>
     <%=Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:D}", item.Modify_Date))%>     
<%} %>
```

There must be something similar in Razor. Hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: Yep this would also work in Razor syntax, e.g. @Html.Encode(string.Format("0:D", item.Modify_Date))

Answer (score 4):

Include Data Annotations like DisplayFormat and ApplyFormatInEditMode to have the desired output.

`[Display(Name = "Bill Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime BillDate { get; set; }`

**Now your Bill date will show like.**

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at the other answers. Do you think yours is necessary and adds some new quality content to the post?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply convert the datetime. Something like:

```
@Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Model.Returndate))
```

Comment: Thanks @ANJYR, this one did the trick for me. I am using PickADay library for DateTime fields. Maybe that is why any of the other proposed solutions worked in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems with the other solutions on this page, so thought I'd drop this in.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, "{0:d}", new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
```

So you only need to add "{0:d}" in the second parameter and you should be good to go.