# How to set default value to the input[type="date"]

Tags: html, date, html-input

I have tried ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VD2QH/2/)):

```html
<input type="date" value="2012-3-23">
```

but it doesn't work, how can I set the default value?

Comment: The value is set in FF16, what browser are you using?

Comment: @KevinBowersox: chrome 23

Comment: [Here are some examples of how you could able to add default date or customize date using jquery and javascript.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55511212/5695622)

Comment: This question should not be marked as duplicate. There is a difference wether you get a default value from the server or just want the today value. This is true especially for localized formats, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57165475/475997

Answer (score 446, accepted):

The date should take the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Single digit days and months should be padded with a 0. January is 01.

From the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.value):

> A string representing a date.

> Value: A valid full-date as defined in [[RFC 3339]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339), with the additional qualification that the year component is four or more digits representing a number greater than 0.

Your code should be altered to:

```html
<input type="date" value="2013-01-08">
```

[Example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DfkU5/)

Comment: Ah thanks for this!  I am defaulting to today's date with php, and I didn't realize that my problem was just the formatting of the date.  I was doing

  <input type="date" value="<?php echo date('m/d/Y'); ?>" name="date" id="date" title="Pick a date" />  

And a variety of other ways, but what works was your suggestion of

value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" Brilliant, thank you!

Comment: I had to use 'yyyy-MM-dd' for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This isn't working on mobile-safari.

Comment: It is not working on my Ionic APp

Comment: @sheriffderek . This is not supported in all browsers, you need a jquery or similar fallback solution

Comment: Preferred solution!

Answer (score 54):

`<input type="date" id="myDate" />`

**Then in js :**

```
_today: function () {
  var myDate = document.querySelector(myDate);
  var today = new Date();
  myDate.value = today.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
},
```

Comment: Thanks! The most simple solution. So weird that it's not popular. Are there any pitfalls with it?

Comment: @AntonSutarmin `toISOString()` returns the date in UTC, not the browser's local time. That may or may not be a pitfall.

Comment: Seems substr is [Deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), but `today.toISOString().substring(0, 10)` works just as well.

Answer (score 37):

A possible solution:

```
document.getElementById("yourDatePicker").valueAsDate = new Date();
```

Using Moment.js:

```
var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
document.getElementById("datePicker").value = today;
```

Comment: Assigning valueAsDate to new Date() assumes that you want the UTC time. If you are in any other time zone other than UTC (0), the date will be incorrect for part of the day.

Comment: See https://austinfrance.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/html5-date-input-field-and-valueasdate-timezone-gotcha-3/

Comment: To tackle ADJenks' case, you can use `(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', timeZone: 'America/New_York'})).formatToParts(date)`. This result you can then map to a `Map` instance, filter out the applicable parts and join with a dash ('-').

Answer (score 28):

if you are using PHP, you can set the value like this

```
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
```

but remember that it would return the date of the server.
e.g. if your server in USA and your client in Indonesia, it may differ 1 day.

But if you want to use from the client, use javascript solution instead.
hope it helps.

Comment: you can also short it a bit <?=date("Y-m-d")?>

Answer (score 5):

You can use this js code:

```
<input type="date" id="dateDefault" />
```

JS

```
function setInputDate(_id){
    var _dat = document.querySelector(_id);
    var hoy = new Date(),
        d = hoy.getDate(),
        m = hoy.getMonth()+1, 
        y = hoy.getFullYear(),
        data;

    if(d < 10){
        d = "0"+d;
    };
    if(m < 10){
        m = "0"+m;
    };

    data = y+"-"+m+"-"+d;
    console.log(data);
    _dat.value = data;
};

setInputDate("#dateDefault");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" name="inicio">
```

Comment: This one worked in my case, `<input type="date" id="reminderDate" class="form-control form-control-user" id="last_name" placeholder="Enter Reminder Date" value='{{customer.reminder_date| date:"Y-m-d" }}'>` in Django.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for setting the current date is.

`<input name="date" type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-j'); ?>" required>`

Answer (score 1):

you can show date by simply following correct format

```html
<input type="date" value="2014-12-29">
```

Answer (score 1):

1. for date:

   ```
   <input type="date" "myDate">
   ============================
   var today = new Date();
   $('#myDate').val(
     today.getFullYear() + '-' +
     ('0' + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
     ('0' + today.getDate()).slice(-2)
   );
   ```
2. for local date and time:

   ```
   <input type="datatime-local" id="myLocalDataTime" step="1">
   ===========================================================
   var today = new Date();
   $('#myLocalDataTime').val(
     today.getFullYear() + '-' +
     ('0' + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
     ('0' + today.getDate()).slice(-2) + 
     'T'+today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes()
    );
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date=date("Y-m-d");
echo"$date";
echo"<br>SELECT DATE: <input type='date'  name='date'  id='datepicker' 
value='$date' required >";
```

Answer (score 1):

// html code

```
<input id="idFdate" type="date" />
```

// javascript code on main load function

```
function loadFunction() {
    // body...
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd;
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm;
    } 

    today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;                
    document.getElementById("idFdate").defaultValue =today+"";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JS Code:

```
function TodayDate(){
        let data= new Date();
        return data.getFullYear().toString()+'-' + (data.getMonth()+1).toString()+'-' + data.getDate().toString()
    }
    document.getElementById('today').innerHTML = '<input type="date" name="Data" value="'+TodayDate()+'" ><br>';
```

Html Code:

```
<div id="today" > </div>
```

A little bit rough but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Visual Studio

Date separator **'-'**

@{string dateValue = request.Date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'ddTHH:mm:ss");}

> < input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="date1" value="@dateValue" 
>   >

Answer (score 0):

Here are three statements for three different dates in the form with three type=date fields.

`$inv_date` is the current date:

```
$inv_date = date("Y-m-d");
```

`$inv_date_from` is the first day of the current month:

```
$inv_date_from = date("Y") . "-" . date("m") . "-" . "01";
```

`$inv_date_to` is the last day of the month:

```
$inv_date_to = date("Y-m-t", strtotime(date("Y-m-t")));
```

I hope this helps :)