# DataAnnotation not showing data stored in ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, data-annotations

I have an Edit view. A filled in `ViewModel` is passed in which the user can edit and submit.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Date Effective:</strong>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <p>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.storeConfiguration.DateEffective)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.storeConfiguration.DateEffective)
        </div>
    </div>
```

The view model contains:

```
public DateTime DateEffective { get; set; }
```

This showed the date as a string and allowed easy edits. However, I came across data annotations and found that by adding `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` I was able to get a useful tool to pick a date.

Unfortunately when used in my edit view above, it shows an empty date picker rather than displaying the date that is in the `ViewModel`.

Is it possible to get this date picking tool without erasing the `ViewModel` data from my edit view?

EDIT:

While attempting to track down this bug, I came across this while looking at the 'Inspect Element'

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field DateEffective must be a date." id="storeConfiguration_DateEffective" name="storeConfiguration.DateEffective" type="date" value="11/5/2014">
```

This shows the correct value is still stored there, it's just not being displayed to the user.

EDIT 2:

Preliminary testing has shown that `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]` is working. I don't fully understand it but it seems that that is the format the date needs to be in for the view to access it. From there, the `EditorFor` is able to display it in the date picking tool which is organized MM/dd/yyyy which is fine for me.

If anyone has a solid answer about what this is doing and why, I'll accept it as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212527/how-to-set-default-value-to-the-inputtype-date) the issue may be the date format in which the value property is being set.

Comment: This is what the error message I just found is giving. I think you might be on the right track. `The specified value '11/05/2014' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd'.`