# Retrieving a date from MYSQL in a html form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, function, date

Hi I have a form to add members with their birth date. The input field for birth date is:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="data_nascita" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Birth Date</label>
       <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input name="data_nascita" type="date" class="form-control" id="data_nascita" placeholder="gg/mm/aaaa"  />
       </div>
</div>
```

Data are correctly uploaded to MYSQL and date format is

```
$data_nascita = ($_POST['data_nascita']);
var_dump($data_nascita); => string(10) "2003-04-15"
```

In the database is stored correctly, and it appears as

```
2018-12-14 18:50:48
```

I want to have the possibility to edit the information about the person (i.e. changing the birth date), and I created an edit file where all the database information is retrieved and appears in form fields that can be edited and updated in MYSQL.

Everything works fine except for dates, which appears as gg/mm/aaaa

The code I used for retrieving data is as usual:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT data_nascita FROM volontari WHERE id_volontari = '$id'";
       $res = $mysqli ->query($query);
       $row = $res->fetch_array (MYSQLI_ASSOC);
       $data_nascita = gira_data_db($row['data_nascita']);

    function gira_data_db($data)
    {
        $array = explode( "-" , $data);
        $array2 = array($array[2], $array[1], $array[0]);
        $testo = implode( "/" , $array2);
        return $testo;
    }
?>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="data_nascita" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Birth Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input name="data_nascita" type="date" class="form-control" id="data_nascita" value="<?php echo $data_nascita ?>" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The date retrieved is

```
var_dump(gira_data_db($row['data_nascita']);) => string(10) "15/04/2003"
```

However in my form field the data appears as 00/00/0000. If I echo the date in an input field type=text, it appears correct.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` add that under your opening `<?php` files; what does it show as well as looking at the HTML source. Also, `$id` comes from where?

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner No errors appear. The $id is just the correspondance of the single record I want to check, as I have a series of records.

Comment: Ok. Someone provided an answer for you below, see that.

Comment: Btw, you're open to an serious SQL injection here.

Comment: You are right: I just made the code simpler. On the final writing I will close it for SQL injection. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you explode by '-' array[2] is '14 18:50:48' and it's not valid value for input with date type.

simply change gira_data_db function as follows:

```
function gira_data_db($data)
{
    return date("YYYY-MM-DD", strtotime($data));
}
```

I hope it would help you

Comment: I tried your function but it doesn't work yet. It is strange as you are right in theory, but when I var_dump what comes from MYSQL I don't see any time, just the date formatted properly.

Comment: Just did another check by echoing your function: it gives the proper format date, but still it doesn't appear in my form field

Comment: According to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212527/how-to-set-default-value-to-the-inputtype-date) you need to change date format to YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: I did also what you suggested but nope: same as before

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox Mozilla

Comment: Gosh... just realized that on Safari it works... goddammmm! :-D

Comment: Ok, at this point my question is: why I can see the date in Safari and not in Firefox or in Chrome? I see that the date is properly stored in the MYSQL and properly retrieved from MYSQL. However I don't see it appearing in my input date field on two browser over three. Is there a way to solve it? Thanks a lot!