# how to display date in HTML Date control using angular 13

Tags: html, angular, angular12, angular13

While performing the edit operation using **angular 13**, I'm using HTML input type `date`. When fetching a date from the database, it is not showing the date in the textbox. Kindly help me. 
**update-movie.component.html**

````
      <div class="mb-2">
        <label>Release Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="releaseDate" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="movieService.movieData.releaseDate"
          #releaseDate="ngModel" [value]=movieService.movieData.releaseDate required
          [class.is-invalid]="releaseDate.invalid && releaseDate.touched">
      </div>```
````

Comment: Check that the date has the corresponding format (in my country it's dd/mm/aaaa)

Comment: check this answer if it helps. the procedure it's the same
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53784879/retrieving-a-date-from-mysql-in-a-html-form

Comment: Do you have any errors in the DevTools console ? And please give us an example of a value fetched from the backend for the releaseDate, or even for the whole movieService object.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, instead of `[value]` I used `[ngModel]` and applied `date pipe`.

```
        <label>Release Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="releaseDate" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="movieService.movieData.releaseDate"
          #releaseDate="ngModel" [ngModel]="movieService.movieData.releaseDate | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'" required
          [class.is-invalid]="releaseDate.invalid && releaseDate.touched">
      </div>
```