# Get the value of the date when I edit a input

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to change the date of birth for a field, however when I click on the button edit, the value of the date of birth is empty.

Here is an example

**index.blade**

[image]

**edit.blade**

[image]

The value is empty...

I have tried this:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
<label for="form-group-input-1">Date naissance</label>
<input type="date" name="date_naissance" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" value="{{$eleves->date_naissance}}">
</fieldset>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your code and explanation isn't enough to understand what is going on. Where are you storing the value? Where is the Edit button?

Comment: possoble dicplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212527/how-to-set-default-value-to-the-inputtype-date

Comment: @Thamer belfkih: It's not duplicata.

Comment: Put your code here and don't use image.

Comment: @mthrsj: Sorry, the modification works however, the value of the date of birth previously disappears in the form after each modification.

Comment: He wants to output the value that comes from the db... not a hardcoded value @Thamerbelfkih

Comment: @Miguel Cruz: Yes, Miguel it's ok now. ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite simple. your value date should have a format... And the edit will work if you have it on a form, ect...

```
value="{{$eleves->date_naissance->format('Y-m-d')}}"
```

change this:

```
<input type="date" name="date_naissance" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" value="{{$eleves->date_naissance}}">
</fieldset>
```

to this:

```
<input type="date" name="date_naissance" class="form-control" id="form-group-input-1" value="{{$eleves->date_naissance->format('Y-m-d')}}">
</fieldset>
```

Test it and let me know.

Comment: You're welcome. Mark it as the correct one so if someone else has the same problem we can help them.