# How to put the default datefield in a form with the previous date that was given before django

Tags: python, django, forms, datefield

Well, i am using a datefield. My question is how can i set the default dateField form (in the template) to put it with the previous date that the field has.

```
class enterprisedata(models.Model):

    ....
    date        = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    ....
```

And this is the template where i am using it:

```
<!--Date of foundation-->
   <strong>Fecha de fundación:</strong>
      <div class="form-group">
         <input class= "form-control" type="date" name="date" value="{{enterprise.date}}" >
      </div>
```

See that the form control has the value "enterprise.date", cause i am trying to put the date that it had before the new one...

views.py:

```
def edit_design(request):

    saveChanges = True
    contact = contactData.objects.get(id=0)
    temp = Templates.objects.get(temp_selected=True)
    enterprise = enterprisedata.objects.get(id=0)
    members = teamMembers.objects.filter(existencia=True)
    design = Available_design_page(isSelected=True)
    indexPage = indexDesign.objects.get(id=0)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = EnterpriseForm(instance=enterprise)
        form2 = ContactForm(instance=contact)
        form3 = IndexForm(instance=indexPage)
    else:
        form = EnterpriseForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=enterprise)
        form2 = ContactForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=contact)
        form3 = IndexForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=indexPage)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid() and form3.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form3.save()
            form2.save()
            return redirect('adminview:save_page')
        else:
            diccionario=request.POST
            print('es invalido: ', diccionario)
        return redirect('adminview:edit_design')
    contexto = {'form':form,
                'form2':form2,
                'form3':form3,
                'members':members,
                'design':design,
                'enterprise':enterprise,
                'contact':contact,
                'indexPage':indexPage,
                }
    return render(request, 'adminview/edit_design.html', contexto)
```

If you can help me i will appreciate...

Thank you!.

Comment: you mean that the value in `{{enterprise.date}}` is not getting displayed in your form? Then try giving some space around the brackets and see if that works like this ``{{ enterprise.date }}``

Comment: I tried, and is the same. does not work :/

Comment: can you update this question with the view that you are using, maybe that data is not coming through?

Comment: Ok, updated. i included the view. Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after doing some searching I found out that, the `<input type="date">` is supported only in some browsers and versions, take a look at this link: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_date.asp) it shows the compatibility.

also there is a format that the value atttribute would take in the date it is `YYYY-MM-DD` I found this out in another question on SO, check this answer: [How to set default value to the input[type=“date”]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212527/how-to-set-default-value-to-the-inputtype-date)

So I guess you must check the data for the date that is getting into the html page through the view, and the format.