# ReactStrap: Display default value in Input of type date

Tags: html, reactjs, input, reactstrap

I have this date `Input`:
[image]
I am trying to display a default value:

```
<Input value="2017-06-01" type="date" />
```

But, as you see above, it doesn't get displayed.
I have followed the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date):

> You can set a default value for the input with a date inside the value
> attribute, like so:

```
<input type="date" value="2017-06-01">
```

Comment: Have you tried the `defaultValue="your-date"` attribute?

Comment: Is this your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212527/how-to-set-default-value-to-the-inputtype-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use defaultValue props

```
<Input defaultValue="2017-06-01" type="date" />
```