# asp.net mvc3 Datetime to shortdate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime-format

i'm new to asp.net and mvc3. I'm working with sql server and entity framework and want to display a date in my Details view.

The data type in sql is `DateTime`.

Now what i get is  : `21.03.2013 00:00:00`
What i want is : `21.03.2013`

Right now i'm using:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.PlanBegPlan.Date)
```

Help please ...

My Controller

```
  public ViewResult DetailsTestRelease(int id)
    {
        ViewData["EditTestReleaseId"] = id;

        TRel testrelease = db.TRel.Single(t => t.Id == id);
        Basedata bv = db.BasedataSet.Single(b => b.Id == id);
        ViewData["pid"] = testrelease.ProjectId;
        //ViewData["bid"] = testrelease.Base.Id;

        var tuple = new Tuple<KPI_Container.TRel, KPI_Container.Basedata>(testrelease, bv);

        return View(tuple);
    }
```

---

My View:

```
    @model Tuple<KPI_Container.TRel, KPI_Container.Basedata>


    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    }

    <h2>Soll-Werte</h2>
    <br />
     <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Soll-Werte Testrelease Bearbeiten", "EditTestRelease", new { id = ViewData["EditTestReleaseId"] }, new { Class = "action add", title = "Hier können die Testreleasedaten gepflegt werden." }) 

        @Html.ActionLink("Soll-Planung der Basiswerte", "EditBaseValues", new { id = ViewData["EditTestReleaseId"] }, new { Class = "action add", title = "Zum Ansehen und Bearbeiten der Basiswerte." }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("KPI-Werte anzeigen", "ShowKPIs", new { id = ViewData["EditTestReleaseId"] }, new { Class = "action add", title = "Zum Ansehen der KPI-Werte." })
     </div>



    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
    </script>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1"><span>Planung Testrelease</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2"><span>Management & Koordination</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3"><span>Zusatzservices / Aktivitäten</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4"><span>PPU Services</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-5"><span>Einflussparameter / Steuergrößen</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
        <table id="tabletry">
        <tr>
        <th>Testrelease</th>
        <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td title="Name des Testrelease">Name</td>
        <td style="background-color: White">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item1.Name)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td title="Name des Projektes">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item1.ProjectId, "Projekt")</td>
        <td style="background-color: White">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item1.Project.Name)</td>
        </tr>


        </table>
        <br />

    <table id="tabletry">
    <tr>
    <th>Soll-Werte</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Plan( Control)</td>
    <td title="Planned Begin Planning - Geplanter Beginn der Testplanung aus der Baseline">PlanBegPlan</td>
    <td style="background-color: White">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item1.PlanBegPlan)</td>
    <td title="Planned End Planning - Geplantes Ende der Testplanung aus der Baseline">PlanEndPLan</td>
    <td style="background-color: White">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item1.PlanEndPlan.Date)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Prep</td>
    <td title="Planned Begin Preparation- Geplanter Beginn der Testvorbereitung aus der Baseline">PlanBegPrep</td>
    <td style="background-color: White">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item1.PlanBegPrep.Date)</td>
    <td title="Planned End Preparation - Geplantes Ende der Testvorbereitung aus der Baseline">PlanEndPrep</td>
    <td style="background-color: White">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item1.PlanEndPrep.Date)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Exec</td>
    <td title="Planned Begin Execution- Geplanter Beginn der Testdurchführung aus der Baseline">PlanBegExec</td>
    <td style="background-color: White">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item1.PlanBegExe.Date)</td>
    <td title="Planned End Execution- Geplantes Ende der Testdurchführung aus der Baseline">PlanEndExec</td>
    <td style="background-color: White">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item1.PlanEndExe.Date)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td title="Planned Begin Total- Geplanter Beginn des Gesamtprojektes aus der Baseline">PlanBegTot</td>
    <td style="background-color: White">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item1.PlanBegTot.Value.Date)</td>
    <td title="Planned End Total- Geplantes Ende des Gesamtprojektes aus der Baseline">PlanEndTot</td>
    <td style="background-color: White">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item1.PlanEndTot.Value.Date)</td>
    </tr>

    </table>
   </div>
   <div id="tabs-2">
        <table id="tabletry">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Soll-Werte</th>
                    <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="xx">Projektmanagement</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.PM_plan)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="xx">Qualitätsmanagement</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.QM_plan)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="xx">Projektmanagement Office</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.PMO_plan)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="xx">Teamkoordination</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.Tcoord_plan)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs-3">
                <table id="tabletry">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Soll-Werte</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="xx">Defektmanagement</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.Defmgmt_plan)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="xx">Umgebungsmanagement</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.Envmgmt_plan)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="xx">Testdatenmanagement</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.Testdmgmt_plan)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="xx">Testvorbereitung</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.Testprep_plan)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="xx">Knowledgetransfer/Transition</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.KTTrans_plan)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="xx">Consulting</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.Consulting_plan)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td title="xx">Tools-Setup</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.Toolset_plan)</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs-4">
                <h2>Funktionaler Test</h2>
                 <table id="tabletry">
                <tr>
                        <th title="xx">Neue<br />Funktionalität</th>
                        <th title="xx">Anzahl geplant<br />hoch</th>
                        <th title="xx">Anzahl geplant<br />mittel</th>
                        <th title="xx">Anzahl geplant<br />gering</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Specification</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.FUN_Tspec_nf_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.FUN_Tspec_nf_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.FUN_Tspec_nf_s_plan)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Execution</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.FUN_TEXe_nf_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.FUN_TExe_nf_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.FUN_TExe_nf_s_plan)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <th>Regression</th>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted;background-color:silver"></td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted;background-color:silver"></td>
                        <td style="background-color:silver"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Specification</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white" >@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.FUN_Tspec_reg_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.FUN_Tspec_reg_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.FUN_Tspec_reg_s_plan)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Execution</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.FUN_TExe_reg_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.FUN_TExe_reg_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style=" background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.FUN_TExe_reg_s_plan)</td>
                </tr>
                </table>

                    <br />
                    <br />
                <h2> Testautomatisierung</h2>
                <table id="tabletry">
                <tr>
                        <th title="xx">Neue<br />Funktionalität</th>
                        <th title="xx">Anzahl geplant<br />hoch</th>
                        <th title="xx">Anzahl geplant<br />mittel</th>
                        <th title="xx">Anzahl geplant<br />gering</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Specification</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.TAU_Tspec_nf_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.TAU_Tspec_nf_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.TAU_Tspec_nf_s_plan)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Execution</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.TAU_TEXe_nf_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.TAU_TExe_nf_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.TAU_TExe_nf_s_plan)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <th>Regression</th>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted;background-color:silver"></td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted;background-color:silver"></td>
                        <td style="background-color:silver"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Specification</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white" >@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.TAU_Tspec_reg_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.TAU_Tspec_reg_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.TAU_Tspec_reg_s_plan)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Execution</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.TAU_TExe_reg_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.TAU_TExe_reg_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style=" background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.TAU_TExe_reg_s_plan)</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                <h2>Last&Performance Test</h2>
                <table id="tabletry">
                <tr>
                        <th title="xx">Neue<br />Funktionalität</th>
                        <th title="xx">Anzahl geplant<br />hoch</th>
                        <th title="xx">Anzahl geplant<br />mittel</th>
                        <th title="xx">Anzahl geplant<br />gering</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Specification</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.LPT_Tspec_nf_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.LPT_Tspec_nf_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.LPT_Tspec_nf_s_plan)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Execution</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.LPT_TEXe_nf_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.LPT_TExe_nf_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.LPT_TExe_nf_s_plan)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <th>Regression</th>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted;background-color:silver"></td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted;background-color:silver"></td>
                        <td style="background-color:silver"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Specification</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white" >@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.LPT_Tspec_reg_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.LPT_Tspec_reg_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.FUN_Tspec_reg_s_plan)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Execution</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.LPT_TExe_reg_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.LPT_TExe_reg_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style=" background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.LPT_TExe_reg_s_plan)</td>
                </tr>
                </table>

                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <h2>Security Test</h2>
                <table id="tabletry">
                <tr>
                        <th title="xx">Neue<br />Funktionalität</th>
                        <th title="xx">Anzahl geplant<br />hoch</th>
                        <th title="xx">Anzahl geplant<br />mittel</th>
                        <th title="xx">Anzahl geplant<br />gering</th>
                     @*   <th title="xx">Aufwand geplant</th>*@
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Specification</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.SEC_Tspec_nf_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.SEC_Tspec_nf_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: groove;background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.SEC_Tspec_nf_s_plan)</td>
                        @* <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.SEC_Tspec_Eff_plan)</td>*@
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Execution</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.SEC_TEXe_nf_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.SEC_TExe_nf_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: groove;background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.SEC_TExe_nf_s_plan)</td>
                    @*    <td style="background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.SEC_TExe_Eff_plan)</td>*@
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <th>Regression</th>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted;background-color:silver"></td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted;background-color:silver"></td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: groove;background-color:silver"></td>
                    @*    <td style="border-right-style: groove;background-color:silver"></td>*@
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Specification</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white" >@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.SEC_Tspec_reg_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.SEC_Tspec_reg_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: groove;background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.SEC_Tspec_reg_s_plan)</td>
                   @*     <td style="border-right-style: groove;background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.SEC_Tspec_Eff_plan)</td>*@
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>Execution</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.SEC_TExe_reg_l_plan)</td>
                        <td style="border-right-style: dotted; background-color: white">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.SEC_TExe_reg_m_plan)</td>
                        <td style=" background-color: white; border-right-style: groove">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item2.SEC_TExe_reg_s_plan)</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>


    </div>


  }  

<div>
     @Html.ActionLink("Zurück", "Details", new { id = ViewData["pid"] })
</div>
```

I build my Model with entity Framework
i got a table 'TRel' and a Table 'Basedata'

Comment: Can you show a complete codes of your view and model? because the answers of people below should be working. I think there is something wrong on how you call and display you model.

Comment: I dont know how to show you the code of my model. I build it with entity Framework.

Comment: I'd expect the parts of your view where you are using e.g. `DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item1.PlanEndPlan.Date`) (with a capital M for Model) to cause an error.  Try replacing these instances with something such as `DisplayFor(m => m.Item1.PlanEndPlan.Date)`.

Comment: @ngm i changed `DisplayFor(Model => Model.Item1.PlanEndPlan.Date)`to `DisplayFor(m=> m.Item1.PlanEndPlan.Date)`.. but i still see  `21.03.2013 00:00:00 ` and not `21.03.2013`

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

Following your last comments I have done some checking and found the following.

1. To display the date in the default short format for your Culture you can use:

   ```
   Model.PlanBegPlan.Date.ToShortDateString()
   ```

   Alternatively you can use the following so the format won't be dependent on the Regional settings:

   ```
   Model.PlanBegPlan.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
   ```

   This can also be wrapped in a `@Html.Display`, as per below, but not a `@Html.DisplayFor` as the latter requires a lambda returning a field or property and both of the above return string values.

   ```
   @Html.Display(Model.PlanBegPlan.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"))
   ```
2. The other option is to specify the date format on your model by using a DisplayFormat attribute on your `Date` property.

   ```
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   ```

   Then in the view you can just put:

   ```
   @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PlanBegPlan.Date)
   ```

   This option allows you to use `DisplayFor`.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I tried both options..but it didnt work! exception : invalidoperationexception templates can be used only with field access

Any ideas?

Comment: @Christina0702. This means you can't use a templates such as `DisplayFor` with a lamda expression, it is possible to use them with fields and properties. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: hm.. when i try  you uopdated code...   `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model.PlanBegPlan.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))</td>` is it underlined in red.

Comment: @Christina0702 try to run it. Sometime the syntax checker gets confused and complains when there isn't a problem.

Comment: @Christina0702 just noticed you have an extra bracket at the end of your expression. It should read: `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model.PlanBegPlan.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>`

Comment: i tried and i got a error message again **CS0135: 'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'**

Comment: @Christina0702 I have done some checking and updated my post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: okay.. i got it!!! i Create an editor template called DateTime.ascx... works just fine. Thanks for you help. :)

Comment: when i try this `@Html.Display(Model.PlanBegPlan.Date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"))` i get an Error Message **CS0135: 'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'**

Comment: Please could you post the @model declaration from your Details view.

Comment: `@model Tuple<KPI_Container.TRel, KPI_Container.Basedata>`

Comment: @Christina0702 please can you update the question to show the View, Model and controller action method?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ToShortDateString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx)  method on the datetime object you have.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.PlanBegPlan.Date.ToShortDateString())
```

The string returned by the `ToShortDateString` method is culture-sensitive. It reflects the pattern defined by the current culture's `DateTimeFormatInfo` object. For example, for the en-US culture, the standard short date pattern is "`M/d/yyyy`"; for the de-DE culture, it is "`dd.MM.yyyy`"; for the ja-JP culture, it is "`yyyy/M/d`".

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.PlanBegPlan.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```

[More reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124434/display-only-date-and-no-time-c-sharp)

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

Thanks everyone. I tried both options

@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.PlanBegPlan.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) @Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.PlanBegPlan.Date.ToShortDateString())

but it didnt work! exception : invalidoperationexception templates can be used only with field access

Any ideas?