# Remove the time part and convert date time in different format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, format, type-conversion

I have a date time object ,Whose time part I am extracting by this

```
var dateAndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(certificate.GetEffectiveDateString());
var date = dateAndTime.Date;
```

date is returning a value :`10/23/2013 12:00:00 AM` where is should only return `10/23/2013` 
Don't know why the time part is not removed.

After time part is removed, I need date to be converted in to this format
`October 23,2013`.

Can we remove the time part and change it into this format by some formats defined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display only date and no time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124434/display-only-date-and-no-time)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There in no convertion in datetime. If you have a string to datetime, use a DateTime.TryParse. If you have a datetime and want a formatted string. You can use a format string:

```
dateAndTime.ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy");
```

will give you a formatted date string.

Answer (score 3):

Use following to get format October 23, 2013

```
dt.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

[Date Time formats](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19677/Formats-for-DateTime-ToString)

Answer (score 2):

The `DateTime.Date` is just a `DateTime` with the time portion set to zero, or midnight.  If you are trying to output it as a string, then you can use either `ToShortDateString()` or one of the many various custom formats.

```
date.ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy")
```

should give you the output you are looking for.

For information on `DateTime.Date`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx

For more information on format strings for `DateTime`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the standard date formats.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use the Date property:

OR

```
 var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
   dateAndTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

The date variable will contain the date, the time part will be 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean that after `ToString` the time is rendered along with the date. Use [`ToShortDateString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) method for example to get what you expect. There are many other possible ways to format a date as string, you can easily find them all [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx). The second format you mention can be achieved for example with:

```
date.ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy");
```

using this [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) overload.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve date only string representation, you can use

`dateTime.ToString("d")`

format, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of doing this, the simplest and most effective, would be like so;

```
DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy") //Return October 23,2013
```

See this [URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) and this [URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for further reading on custom dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
// returns a date 'MM/dd/yyyy' string from a datetime string '2014-06-19 00:00:00.000'
public static string stripTime(string s) {
    string date = "";
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(s);
    date = dt.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    return date;
}
// returns a date 'MM/dd/yyyy'string  from a datetime datetime 
public static string stripTime(DateTime d) {
    string date = "";
    date = d.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely this would work:

```
var dateAndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(certificate.GetEffectiveDateString());
var date = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, dateTime.Day);
```

I haven't tried myself however, but it should give the result you want.
You could even create an Extension Method for it:

```
public static class DateExtension
{
    public DateTime ToDateOnly(this DateTime d)
    {
       return new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day);
    }
}
```