# How to change type="datetime" to HTML5 standard type="date" when using MVC EditorFor without custom Editor Template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

I've got an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. Date fields are prolific. Things are working and behaving propertly, however the W3C Markup Validator complains about the date text fields having an improper `type` attribute value.

I'm rendering the `input`'s for `DateTime` or nullable `DateTime` properties using the `EditorFor` helper:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeginDate)
```

This is getting translated to:

```html
<input type="datetime">
```

The "datetime" value of the `type` attribute is no longer a standard according to the [W3C HTML5 Forms standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-type-keywords). The supported date/time types are:

- date - A date (year, month, day) with no time zone
- time - A time (hour, minute, seconds, fractional seconds) with no time zone

I don't really want to create a custom Editor Template, because the standard MVC editor template works perfectly, *except the `type="datetime"` attribute value is non-standard.*

**How can I override the default behavior of the `EditorFor` method for DateTime objects so it creates `<input type="date">` elements without creating my own Editor Template?**

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124434/display-only-date-and-no-time.  The link only talks about displaying a short date string.  it has nothing to do with the input tag having the correct html5 data type.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: I agree with Fran.This has nothing to do with the display, and everything to do with the rendered HTML.

Comment: then vote for reopen :)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: I did vote to reopen the question. :)

Comment: So do i did....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotate your model field with the DataType attribute

```
public class Model1
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime BegineDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Which namespace is the `DataType` enum in? I'm not able to resolve that symbol to a namespace in my current project. I'm wondering if I'm missing an assembly reference.

Comment: using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. I'm using NHibernate, which has a class NHibernate.Type.DataType, and then there is System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType. My problem is clash of namespaces. Visual studio just got weird on my briefly.

Comment: Works perfectly! Now to just get Microsoft to change the default behavior of the MVC framework...