# display only the date and not the time in c# from sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Hi I have this code in my .cs file and the output is 5/27/2017 12:00:00 AM but I want it to format only the date like 5/27/2017. This is my code to show the value in the label. If I add any parameter in the ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") it tells me No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments.

```
 Date.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AUM"].ToString();
```

Comment: is `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AUM"]` actually a `DateTime` object? If so look at [ToShortTimeString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast to date time first

```
Date.Text = ((DateTime)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AUM"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Beautiful! It works!!!

Comment: Mark the answer as correct, please. Thanks!

Comment: There are better options as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124434/display-only-date-and-no-time. This is indeed "one that helped me the most of half-answers to my post" and should be check-marked as "answer", but for real answer look at linked duplicate.

Comment: I agree it looks like the same question (the title) but the content in the answers were different and the answers in that post didn't help me.

Comment: If the sql data type of the field AUM is date time, then the Row have a C# DateTime in that column, but the value is a Object. You had to cast it to DateTime first. Then.. DateTime have a ToString("format") method

Answer (score 2):

If your data is DateTime:

```
Date.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AUM"].ToShortDateString();
```

If your data is a string:

```
Date.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AUM"]).ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look up these methods when you don't understand how their parameters work. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

That said, if you're pulling a `DateTime` value anyway, you can:

`Date.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AUM"]).ToShortDateString()`;